# How to call a stored procedure which returns a composite type from @Formula?

Tags: hibernate

In a given database the last modification date of records is not stored in the table of the record itself, but is retrieved from a history table by using a stored procedure.

This stored proc returns a composite type. Mapping the last modification date like this, however, does not work:

```
@Formula("(select op_timestamp from get_last_mod('text_header', id))")
private Date lastUpdated;
```

because when transforming this to HQL, Hibernate replaces op_timestamp with _myentity0.op_timestamp. Putting it into quotes also does not work, giving the stored proc result an alias (select last.op_timestamp from .... as last) also has the same result.

The only way I could make it work is to create an alias for the stored procedure in the DB which returns only the timestamp from the composite type:

```
@Formula("get_last_mod_ts('text_header', id)")
private Date lastUpdated;
```

Hibernate experts, do you know the correct syntax to achieve this with the original stored procedure? ( The project uses Hibernate 4.2.1 )

Answer (score 1):

use function

```
@Formula(value = "(SELECT func_last_mod_ts('text_header',id))")

CREATE FUNCTION func_last_mod_ts(@pHEADER VARCHAR(50), @pID INT) 
RETURNS INT 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @ret INT;
(
    SELECT @ret = 1

) RETURN @ret;
END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, consider including a short explanation as to why this provides an answer.